# Why kartoza/geoserver can't let me loggin in?

Tags: nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy, geoserver

I have [kartoza/geoserver](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver) that I start with this docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  geoserver:
    image: kartoza/geoserver
    environment:
      - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_USER
      - GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD
      - GEOSERVER_CSRF_DISABLED=true
      - JAVA_OPTS
      #- PROXY_BASE_URL
```

running behind Nginx with these configurations:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name geos.mydomain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert/geoserver/geoserver.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert/geoserver/geoserver.rsa;

        location /geoserver/ {
                proxy_pass http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/;
                proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

}
```

I can see the geoserver page:
[image]

But when I try to login it fails:
[image]
[image]

Why? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mazano](https://github.com/NyakudyaA) said:

Looks like you are running with HTTPS so you need to set the following env variables

```
HTTP_PROXY_NAME=foo.org HTTP_SCHEME=https
```

after setting these variables everything works fine!